# What is equivalent of DatatypeFactory and XMLGregorianCalendar in c#?

Tags: java, c#, .net

I am trying to convert following code into c#.
I didn't find equivalent of DatatypeFactory and XMLGregorianCalendar in c#.
How can I convert it to C#?

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
    // do not forget the type cast :/
    GregorianCalendar gcal = (GregorianCalendar) GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
    XMLGregorianCalendar xgcal = DatatypeFactory.newInstance()
          .newXMLGregorianCalendar(gcal);
    System.out.println(xgcal);
}
```

EDIT : Goal is to get Date from XMl string and put into my date variable.

Comment: What are you trying to *achieve*? Yes, whatever it is, you've achieved it using `XMLGregorianCalendar` in Java - but that doesn't tell us what the actual goal is. (And please put more effort into formatting your posts in future. After asking 117 questions, you should be able to make sure your text doesn't come out as code...)

Answer (score 0):

My java days are long gone, but I think the OP tries to print the current date in ISO 8601 format. Try:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.UtcNow.ToString(@"yyyy-MM-ddTHH\:mm\:ss.fffffffzzz"));
}
```

But the standard defines multiple formats.